# How can i change the visibilty of an image placeholder if its src is empty or a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm a trainee and actually I'm working on a web shop.
Now I got the problem that I have multiple images placeholders (image_1-6) for our article images. Problem now is, if the article only has 2 images the placeholders for the other 4 are still there. So is there any possibility to hide them if the `src` is empty or a parameter defined by me?

Here is the code snippet:

```html
<div class="sideimg grid_2">
  <div id="image_1" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild1]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild1]"id=image1 name="Bild1" alt="Bild1" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="image_2" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild2]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild2]" id=image2 name="Bild2" alt="Bild2" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="image_3" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild3]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild3]" id=image3 name="Bild3" alt="Bild3" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="image_4" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild4]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild4]" id=image4 name="Bild4" alt="Bild4" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="image_5" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild5]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild5]" id=image5 name="Bild5" alt="Bild5" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="image_6" class="lb_thumb">
    <a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="swapImage('Bild1','','http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleBig/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild6]',1)" onmouseout="swapImgRestore()">
      <img class="lb_detailimg" src="http://media-11teamsports.de/ArticleSmall/[ArtikelOnlinebezeichnungD.Bild6]" id=image6 name="Bild6" alt="Bild6" id="Bild2" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the live version(wip): http://www.ebay.de/itm/Jako-Tape-10-Meter-2-5-cm-breit-Rot-F01-/272269970423?

All I know about html css and js I learned by myself so I hope the snippet is fine.
So as you can see I have 6 images with js image swap. The only left problem is that our database don't contains an image for every placeholder, so if there are only 4 pictures there are still 2 empty boxes. So how can i get rid of them?

Thanks all for your help and excuse my english I'm from Germany.

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: Where is your snippet?

Comment: first it didn't showed up now i added it, of course it dont looks how it looks at the webshop. Should i add the css or the full code?

Comment: Kind of need to see the javascript function as well.

Comment: http://www.ebay.de/itm/Jako-Tape-10-Meter-2-5-cm-breit-Rot-F01-/272269970423? here you can see it live in action

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the CSS selector for html attributes like this:

```
.lb_detailimg[src]{
    (Whatever css u need goes here)
    display: block;
}
.lb_detailimg{
    display: none;
}
```

If any `<img>` of class `lb_detailimg` does not have a `src` attribute it will not be displayed.

You could also use a keyword in the `src` attribute to make this happen, like this:

```
.lb_detailimg{
    (Whatever css u need goes here)
}
.lb_detailimg[src=keyword]{
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT:

As you cannot give style to a parent element in CSS here is a JS snippet that should work fine:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var img_containers = document.getElementsByClassName("lb_thumb");
    for(var i=0; i<img_containers.length;i++){
        if(img_containers[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src.indexOf("keyword") > -1){
            img_containers[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

At line 4 in the `if` ==> `.indexOf(`"yourKeyWordHere"`)`

Comment: Your other choices are using javascript or delete/edit elements server side.

Comment: works fine but now is only the img tag hidden not the full div(where the image is placed) is there a possiblity to hide the full div(.lb_thumb)?

Comment: I believe this could be achieved using JQuery's `.parent()` method  [JQuery .parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: There is no way to "go up" so to speak in css. You can go down like this `div > img` this selects all `<img>` that are within a `<div>` however you can not do `div < img[src]` to select the parent div of any `<img>` with a `src` attribute.

You would have to use js/JQuery or a serverside solution.

Comment: so i have to us jquery's .parent() method?

Comment: Yes, JS or jQuery. Provided js above, under "EDIT:"